# Swift for iOS - 2 for loops run at the same time?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have two objects where I need to update their UI at the same time. I have a for loop for one, and after that another for loop. Each iteration in the for loop I have a short delay so that for elements in the object I am making a UI change... one after the other - not seemingly all at once.

```
func update(value: Int){
    var delay: Double = 0.05
    // first loop
    for i in 0...value {
        delayWithSeconds(delay) {
            //do something with object 1
        }
        delay = delay + 0.05
     }

     var delay2: Double = 0.05
     // second loop
     for i in 0...value {
        delayWithSeconds(delay2) {
            //do something with object 2
        }
        delay2 = delay2 + 0.05
    }
}

// Utility
func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

I have tried wrapping each for loop with `DispatchQueue.main.async` and it didn't make a difference. In short - I would like to run both for loops at the same time (or perceived as such). These are on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seemed to work out quite well. It does exactly what I want it to do (at least visually they seem to run at the same time).

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "net.ericd.hello", attributes: .concurrent)
concurrentQueue.async {
    //my loop with delay here for object 1.
}
concurrentQueue.async {
    //my separate loop with delay here for object 2.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use it when we want execute different arrays at the same time:

```
using this Generic Function
zip(_:_:)
```

Here i took 2 array:

```
var arrOfInt = ["1","2","3"]
var arrOfIntString = ["one","two","three"]
for (intNum, intString) in zip(arrOfInt, arrOfIntString) {
    print("Int:\(intNum), String:\(intString)")
}
```